# xlsxwriter conditional format data bars options not working

Tags: python, excel, conditional-formatting, xlsxwriter

I am trying to use `xlsxwriter` to outsheet a table that has conditional formatted data bars. For some reason, this only seems to work when I specify the code with no optional parameters, or just with the color change parameter. None of the other parameters work `('data_bars_2010', 'bar_direction', 'bar_negative_color_same')`.

The docs [Working with Conditional Formatting](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html) say you need excel 2010 or higher, and I am currently using a 2013 version. Maybe this has to do with my version of `xlsxwriter` not being up to date.

In terms of the code: this basic example works:

```
worksheet8.conditional_format('B3:B14', {'type': 'data_bar'})

worksheet8.conditional_format('F3:F14', {'type': 'data_bar',
                                         'bar_color': '#63C384'})
```

But these more stylized options do not work and result in no bars showing up at all.

```
worksheet8.conditional_format('J3:J14', {'type': 'data_bar',
                                         'bar_direction': 'right'})

worksheet8.conditional_format('L3:L14', {'type': 'data_bar',
                                         'data_bar_2010': True})

worksheet8.conditional_format('M3:N14', {'type': 'data_bar',
                                         'bar_negative_color_same': True,
                                         'bar_negative_border_color_same': True})
```

Comment: What version of Excel and what version of XlsxWriter are you using? Also are there any warnings when running the code?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you gave the Excel version as 2013. In that case make sure you have a version of XlsxWriter >= 1.0.3 (but preferably newer). In older versions you will get a warning and no data bars (like your case).

Answer (score 1):

You were totally correct. Once I updated to xlsxwriter 1.3.3, the data bars worked!